# How to set unselected Text Color for TabLayout.Tab - Android

Tags: android, android-tablayout

How do you set text-color for a tab that's not selected?  I know you can set the text-color for the TabLayout by doing: **setTabTextColors**

Comment: Why don't you give default color to text and change it on selection?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `app:tabTextColor` for default tab color and `app:tabSelectedTextColor` for selected tab color.

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="#000000"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style`:

Add in `styles.xml`:

```xml
<style name="CustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
     <item name="tabTextColor">@color/default_text_color</item>
</style>
```

use in xml

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    style="@style/CustomTabLayout"
 />
```